# create one list from one list with random sample

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, random

I have a list, then I want to pick 2 elements (`RandomSample[list,2]`) put them in a new list (those two element will be one element in the new list, like list of lists) and delete them from the my inicial list and follow the process until my first list turn empty. I need that my out be a list of lists of the random sample elements. What can I do?

Comment: It's hard to understand what your desired input and output are. Can you give an example?

Comment: Why not just do `Partition[RandomSample[list], 2]`? Basically, you prescramble the starting list, and just take two elements at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a list

```
list = Range[20]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20} *)
```

The better approach, as JM already said is to scramble your original list

```
RandomSample[list]
(* {3, 20, 6, 7, 15, 13, 10, 11, 16, 4, 9, 14, 8, 12, 1, 17, 18, 2, 19, 5} *)
```

Now, you only need to partition this list and you are done

```
Partition[%, 2]
(* {{3, 20}, {6, 7}, {15, 13}, {10, 11}, {16, 4}, {9, 14}, 
   {8, 12}, {1, 17}, {18, 2}, {19, 5}} *)
```